# LocalStoring an array on Intel XDK

Tags: arrays, json, html, cordova, intel-xdk

```
if(window.localStorage.getItem("_cevaplar")!==undefined
                   || window.localStorage.getItem("_sorular")!==undefined){
                    cevaplar = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("_cevaplar"));
                    sorular = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("_sorular"));
                }
```

When I use this code, it returns the default value. I also checked Intel's documentation, but there is no other information about array storing. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a localStorage item has no value it has null vale, not undefined.

```
if(window.localStorage.getItem("_cevaplar")!==null
                   || window.localStorage.getItem("_sorular")!==null){
                    cevaplar = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("_cevaplar"));
                    sorular = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("_sorular"));
                }
```